# Наследование от собственного элемента управления WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу сделать один класс, допустим Icons, который будет содержать свойства, общие для всех потомков этого класса. А от этого класса Icons сделать элементы управления допустим Red_Icon, Sett_Icon. И соответственно внутри этих потомков будут переопределены некоторые свойства/функции. Как это сделать в WPF? В WinForms таких проблем не было, потому что как обычные классы, так и элементы управления имели всего 1 файл, который можно было наследовать от чего угодно, в случае с WPF такое не прокатывает

https://prnt.sc/p1pfq3

И вот тут изначально эта ошибка, нейм спейс такой же, если прописать local: он сам предлагает дописать этот класс, но когда его выбираешь, возникает эта ошибка

Comment: `в случае с WPF такое не прокатывает` спорное утверждение. Вы приведите пример кода, что у вас не работает.

Comment: Мне нужен просто пример наследования элементов управления в впф. Как я уже написал Icons наследован от UserControl, к примеру, а у Icons уже будут потомки Red_Icon, Sett_Icon и тд. Пример подобного кода тут тяжело будет вставить =(

Comment: При создании элемента управления, создается два файла, XAML и CS. И базовый класс и в XAML, и в CS должен быть одинаковый. Но в XAML я могу указать только Window, UserControl либо Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убедитесь, что вы изменили первый тег в xaml, чтобы он также наследовал ваш новый базовый тип

Было

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestDependencyProperty827.DataTypes.DataTypeWholeNumber"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
>
```

Стало

```
<myTypes:BaseDataType x:Class="TestDependencyProperty827.DataTypes.DataTypeWholeNumber"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:myTypes="clr-namespace:TestDependencyProperty827.DataTypes"
    >
```

Несколько замечаний:

- Базовый класс не должен включать файл xaml. Определите его в одном
  (non-partial) файле CS и определите его для наследования
  непосредственно из Usercontrol.
- Убедитесь, что подкласс наследует от
  базового класса как в файле с выделенным кодом cs, так и в первом
  теге xaml (как показано выше).

Comment: Файл XAML пишет "Icons не существует в пространстве имен ...". Хотя пространство имен то же самое. Переменную пространства имен в XAML`е я сделал

Comment: Вообще лучше если вы приложите код, который не работает. В моем примере просто приведено как работает наследование. Вот пример наследования даже с проектом http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.com/2009/09/user-control-inheritance-in-wpf.html

Comment: Выше прикрепил скрин

Comment: Так там нет Icons. И проверить нельзя, так как это скриншот. Скорее всего что-то испортилось в структуре проекта. Попробуйте разобраться с приведенным проектом и сделать ваш проект заново.

Comment: Да, это другой проект, но суть та же. Файл Automobile у меня создан, в нем класс с названием Automobile , он в этом же неймспейсе DragAndDrop(по умолчанию прописывается). Но почему-то ошибка, будто такого класса нет. Модификаторы доступа у всех классов public

Comment: Я понимаю, что вас это очень беспокоит, но без полного кода проекта невозможно определить ошибку, уж простите.

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался с проблемой. Оказывается это MVS помечало это как ошибку, но после компиляции ошибка исчезала